# Why is my unordered list changing the line?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

Nav links in nav bar are dropping down outside of the nav bar, how do I keep the nav links inside the nav bar?

At the moment it looks like this, but i want to have it displayed inline:

[Take a look at this, shows what i currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBpUb.png)

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>PAVILLONS DIREKT SB-Pavillons Miet-Mobilbanken Miet-SV-Pavillons Bankentechnik</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favi-logo.png">
        <meta name="author" content="Pavillons Direkt">
        <meta name="publisher" content="Pavillons Direkt">
        <meta name="copyright" content="Pavillons Direkt 2015">
        <meta name="keywords" content="SB-Pavillon,Pavillons,Miet-Mobilbanke,Mobilbanken,Mobilbank,Miet-Mobilbanken,Miet-SB-Pavillon,Miet-SB-Pavillon,Miet-SB-Pavillons, bankcontainer, pod, pods, cash-point, cash-points, city-cash-point,citycashpoint,bank-container,miet-bank,Ritzenthaler,Pavillons Direkt,ash banksystem,nautech,inform,synfis,kompaktbau writz,gunnebo,garny,safecor,leicher,gaalego,wincor nixdorf,ncr,diebold,geldautomat,geldautomaten,telefonzelle,heventa">
        <meta name="description" content="Pavillons Direkt ist Ihr langj&auml;hriger Partner f&uuml;r SB-Pavillons, Miet-Mobilbanken, Miet-SB-Pavillons sowie Banken- und Sicherheitstechnik. Entwicklung, Fertigung, Verkauf, Vermietung und Service aus einer Hand.">
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="de-DE">
        <meta name="robots" content="all">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="mobile-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="mobile-menu-button" href="#mobile-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <header>
            <img id="logo-img" src="images/logo.png">
            <p>Hier kann noch ein Motto hin!</p>
        </header>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Produkte
                    <ul class="product-selector">
                        <li class="product-selector">
                            SB-Pavillons
                            <ul class="product-selector">
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    Outdoor-Line
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Outdoor 4</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Outdoor "New"</a></li>
                                    </ul class="product-selector">
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    Basic-Line
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Basic 4</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Basic 6</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    Business-Line
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Business 8</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Business 12</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    Image-Line
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Image 11</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Image 16</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Individuell</a></li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Gebrauchte</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="product-selector">
                            Miet-Banken
                            <ul class="product-selector">
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    MietMobilbanken
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Mobilbanke 12x3m</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Mobilbank 5x3m</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    MietSBPavillons
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Miet-SB-Pavillon</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">MietSBContainer</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="product-selector">
                            Sonstige
                            <ul class="product-selector">
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Indoor-SB-L&ouml;sungen</a></li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Sonstige 2</a></li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Sonstige 3</a></li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Sonstige 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="partners.html">Partner</a></li>
                <li><a href="intranet.html">Intranet</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section id="main-site">
            <article>
                <h2>Herzlich Willkommen!</h2>
                <p>Willkommen auf unseren Seiten und vielen Dank f&uuml;r Ihr Interesse. Wir m&ouml;chten Ihnen hier einen kurzen Einblick in unser Produktprogramm und unsere M&ouml;glichkeiten geben.</p>
                <p>Sie suchen eine Gesch&auml;ftsstelle zur Miete, die Sie w&auml;hrend des Umbaus Ihrer Filialen oder f&uuml;r Ihre Pr&auml;senz bei Veranstaltungen und Events nutzen k&ouml;nnen? Mit unseren Miet-Mobilbanken und Miet-SB-Pavillons verf&uuml;gen Sie immer &uuml;ber die richtige L&ouml;sung.</p>
                <p>Oder planen Sie f&uuml;r Ihre Kunden eine SB-Gesch&auml;ftsstelle? Mit unserer breiten Auswahl an SB-Pavillons finden Sie sicher auch die f&uuml;r Sie perfekte L&ouml;sung. Durch kurze Lieferzeiten und die M&ouml;glichkeit der Umsetzung bleiben Sie von Anfang an flexibel. Gern fertigen wir auch Ihren ganz individuellen SB-Pavillon.</p>
                <p>Selbstverst&auml;ndlich bieten wir Ihnen auch s&auml;mtliche Dienstleistungen rund um unsere Produkte an. Wartungen, Reparaturen, Renovierung und Umsetzungen geh&ouml;ren ebenso dazu, wie die bauliche Anpassung bei &Auml;nderung der Anforderungen an Ihren SB-Pavillon.</p>
            </article>
            <aside>
                <section>
                    <h2>News</h2>
                </section>
            </aside>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <ul>
                <li><b>&copy; 2015, PAVILLONS DIREKT</b></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="impressum.html"><i class="fa fa-info"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ipressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: .313em .0em .0313em .0em;
    padding: 1.25em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 3.8em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.563em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1.25em;
    text-align: left
}

p {
    line-height: 1.25em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1.25em;
    text-align: justify;
}

img {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Mobile-Menu */

#mobile-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#mobile-menu ul {
    display: block;
    width: 2em;
    padding: .9em;
}

#mobile-menu ul {
    display: inline;
}

#mobile-menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#mobile-menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Head */

header {
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

#logo-img {
    width: 20%;
}

/* Main Nav */

nav {
    display: block;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: #333;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding: .0563em .0938em .375em .0938em;
    transition:background 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.2s;
    color: red;
}

nav ul li ul li ul {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul li ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding: .0563em .0938em .375em .0938em;
    transition:background 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.2s;
    color: red;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding: .0563em .0938em .375em .0938em;
    transition:background 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.2s;
    color: red;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #8C8888;
    border-bottom: 0.188em solid #5298F2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a.current {
    border-bottom: 0.188em solid #5298F2;
}

.product-selector {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please be more specific as to what you want and what the problem is.

Comment: @magreenberg Read the top line now, do you understand the problem?

Comment: [Validate](https://html5.validator.nu/) your HTML before asking.

Comment: @Xufox The validation is the question and the answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid tag placement all over the place. Take this fiddle and fill in the blanks. http://jsfiddle.net/c9dhn9nc/34/

```
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Produkte</a></li>
    <li class="product-selector">Sonstige</li>
    <li><a href="partners.html">Partner</a></li>
    <li><a href="intranet.html">Intranet</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I honestly couldn't see the li or ul that was the issue and is why I shortened the code, just make sure when you put it back, you close the ul and il tags in the correct places, also don't add a class names to a closing tags, and do not nest <a> tags inside each other.

Answer (score 2):

**Your play is on the wrong property**. What you want to do is hide child lists. The correct way of doing this is to toggle the `display: none` to `display: block` or `display: inline-block` properties. What you are intending to do is toggle `visibility: hidden` to `visibility: visible` properties. That is, the crux of your issue.

You need to understand the difference between `display: none` and `visibility: visible`. There's already a question on that here -> [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Just to borrow from Kevin's answer there (which is the marked answer and rightly so) :

> `display:none` means that the tag in question will not appear on the
>   page at all (although you can still interact with it through the dom).
>   There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.
>
> `visibility:hidden` means that unlike display:none, the tag is not
>   visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. The tag is
>   rendered, it just isn't seen on the page.

See below how the change from `visibility: hidden` to `display: none` affects the appearance (*you will need to implement this on all children lists as well*) :

```css
body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: .313em .0em .0313em .0em;
    padding: 1.25em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 3.8em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.563em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1.25em;
    text-align: left
}

p {
    line-height: 1.25em;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1.25em;
    text-align: justify;
}

img {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Mobile-Menu */

#mobile-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#mobile-menu ul {
    display: block;
    width: 2em;
    padding: .9em;
}

#mobile-menu ul {
    display: inline;
}

#mobile-menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#mobile-menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Head */

header {
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

#logo-img {
    width: 20%;
}

/* Main Nav */

nav {
    display: block;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: #333;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding: .0563em .0938em .375em .0938em;
    transition:background 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.2s;
    color: red;
}

nav ul li ul li ul {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul li ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: .0em .188em .0em .188em;
}

nav ul li ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding: .0563em .0938em .375em .0938em;
    transition:background 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.2s;
    color: red;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding: .0563em .0938em .375em .0938em;
    transition:background 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.2s;
    color: red;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #8C8888;
    border-bottom: 0.188em solid #5298F2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a.current {
    border-bottom: 0.188em solid #5298F2;
}

.product-selector {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="mobile-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="mobile-menu-button" href="#mobile-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <header>
            <img id="logo-img" src="images/logo.png">
            <p>Hier kann noch ein Motto hin!</p>
        </header>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Produkte
                    <ul class="product-selector">
                        <li class="product-selector">
                            SB-Pavillons
                            <ul class="product-selector">
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    Outdoor-Line
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Outdoor 4</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Outdoor "New"</a></li>
                                    </ul class="product-selector">
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    Basic-Line
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Basic 4</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Basic 6</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    Business-Line
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Business 8</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Business 12</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    Image-Line
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Image 11</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Image 16</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Individuell</a></li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Gebrauchte</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="product-selector">
                            Miet-Banken
                            <ul class="product-selector">
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    MietMobilbanken
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Mobilbanke 12x3m</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Mobilbank 5x3m</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-selector">
                                    MietSBPavillons
                                    <ul class="product-selector">
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Miet-SB-Pavillon</a></li>
                                        <li class="product-selector"><a href="">MietSBContainer</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="product-selector">
                            Sonstige
                            <ul class="product-selector">
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Indoor-SB-L&ouml;sungen</a></li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Sonstige 2</a></li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Sonstige 3</a></li>
                                <li class="product-selector"><a href="">Sonstige 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="partners.html">Partner</a></li>
                <li><a href="intranet.html">Intranet</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section id="main-site">
            <article>
                <h2>Herzlich Willkommen!</h2>
                <p>Willkommen auf unseren Seiten und vielen Dank f&uuml;r Ihr Interesse. Wir m&ouml;chten Ihnen hier einen kurzen Einblick in unser Produktprogramm und unsere M&ouml;glichkeiten geben.</p>
                <p>Sie suchen eine Gesch&auml;ftsstelle zur Miete, die Sie w&auml;hrend des Umbaus Ihrer Filialen oder f&uuml;r Ihre Pr&auml;senz bei Veranstaltungen und Events nutzen k&ouml;nnen? Mit unseren Miet-Mobilbanken und Miet-SB-Pavillons verf&uuml;gen Sie immer &uuml;ber die richtige L&ouml;sung.</p>
                <p>Oder planen Sie f&uuml;r Ihre Kunden eine SB-Gesch&auml;ftsstelle? Mit unserer breiten Auswahl an SB-Pavillons finden Sie sicher auch die f&uuml;r Sie perfekte L&ouml;sung. Durch kurze Lieferzeiten und die M&ouml;glichkeit der Umsetzung bleiben Sie von Anfang an flexibel. Gern fertigen wir auch Ihren ganz individuellen SB-Pavillon.</p>
                <p>Selbstverst&auml;ndlich bieten wir Ihnen auch s&auml;mtliche Dienstleistungen rund um unsere Produkte an. Wartungen, Reparaturen, Renovierung und Umsetzungen geh&ouml;ren ebenso dazu, wie die bauliche Anpassung bei &Auml;nderung der Anforderungen an Ihren SB-Pavillon.</p>
            </article>
            <aside>
                <section>
                    <h2>News</h2>
                </section>
            </aside>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <ul>
                <li><b>&copy; 2015, PAVILLONS DIREKT</b></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="impressum.html"><i class="fa fa-info"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ipressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
```

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith +1 And I didn't pay much attention to the html. I instead looked at the CSS. I think we may have hit just the tip of the iceberg though!!!